# Does Django tests run slower on the mac compared to linux?

Tags: django

I'm currently developing my Django projects on both:

1. Mac OS X 10.5, 32 bit
2. Ubuntu Server 9.10 64 bits (1 CPU, 512MB RAM)

Both of the above OS are using:

1. Python 2.6.4
2. Django 1.1.1
3. MySQL 5.1

Running 12 tests for one of my application take:

1. Mac: 57.513s
2. Linux: 30.935s

**EDIT:**

Mac Hardware Spec:

- MacBook Pro
- 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 3GB RAM

I'm running the Ubuntu OS on the same mac above through VMware Fusion 2.0.6.

You might argue that Ubuntu Server 64 bits is faster but I have observed a similar speed difference on Ubuntu 8.10 32 bits desktop edition. Even if I turn off my linux VM and other mac applications, I still experience the slowness. Has anyone else experienced this Django test speed difference across those two OS?

**Found the answer:**

Thanks to the comment from *istruble* and the answer from *DZPM* (I've +1 to you since I can't accept an answer in expired bounty question). It looks like the MySQL database as a test database on the mac is causing the performance issue. Using sqlite3 for tests make the test run time comparable on both platforms.

Comment: What kind of hardware do they use, or are they both running on the same machine?

Comment: Have you tried to rule out DB performance differences by running the tests with sqlite3?  Or by running the tests with the Mac pointing to the DB on Ubuntunu and vice versa?  Also, are the user and system values also about 2x larger on your Mac?

Comment: Maybe change the title of this question to "Does Python run slower on a Mac compared to Linux?" and tag it with python, osx and linux.

Comment: This question would have been closed had it not been for the bounty. There's no way to say for sure; I doubt even GvR could answer this question.

Comment: Well, that's not strictly true: As with all performance questions, the correct answer is unambiguously obtainable by measuring, to profile and find out where the slowness lives. But we'd have get hold of his whole source code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your tests, but the bottleneck should be in the database. Could you benchmark *MySQL 5.1* in both platforms?

If that's the case, you should set the database in another machine, then configure your project to use it.

Comment: For that matter, are you SURE your unit tests are running on the production database? By default they run in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

So what *else* is running when you have OSX running? You have Ubuntu Server, which is normally stripped down to just the essentials, running against a desktop OS that's got all kinds of crap running for the "user experience". I'm surprised it did as well as your numbers show.

The only way to truly compare the same app under 2 OSes is to make sure that both OSes are set up in essentially the same way for what you are measuring for.

Comment: It's a dev machine, even after a fresh reboot, the django test on the mac still perform poorly.  I just want to know if other people with both OS are experiencing the same slowness.  If not, then there's probably something wrong with my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Some string operations in Python appear to be significantly slower under OS X than under Ubunutu running on a VM on the same machine.  Try this in your shell and see what kind of results you come up with:

```
from timeit import Timer
def sx():
    for i in range(10000):
        s = "%d" % i

min(Timer(stmt=sx).repeat(number=100, repeat=10))
```

With Python 2.6.4 under OS X 10.6.2 and a 64-bit Ubuntu (unknown version) with kernel version 2.6.31 in a VMware Fusion 2.0.6 VM, the OS X test takes 1.4x as long as the Ubuntu test.  OS X fairs better under Python 3.1 where it takes a little less than 1.1x as long.

This does not explain your ~2x speed difference but it does show that Python can run slower under OS X.

Comment: I'd be astonished if this sort of thing was responsible for the slowness of his Django tests. Generally hitting the database is orders of magnitude slower than anything like this.

Comment: @JonathanHartley  No, the python speed difference does not explain the difference that the question called out but it does point out a possible contributing factor.  The last line in this answer explicitly states that the ~2x speed difference is not explained by this answer.

Comment: Yeah but only a teeny proportion of the time taken to run the tests is spent doing string operations - let's say 1/1000th. Most of the time is spent on filesystem or DB access. Hence if string operations are 1.4 times slower on Macs, then this will cause Macs to run the tests in 1.0004 the time it takes on Ubuntu. (0.999 for the DB & file system stuff, plus 0.001 * 1.4 for the string operations.) So although this technically is contributory, the contribution is so small that to draw attention to it is actively misleading.